# Rows already alphabetically ordered in postgresql. How to use this information in a search?

Tags: sql, postgresql, search

I have a postgresql table "people" with a column called "full_names" (VARCHAR(150)). These full_names I save them already alphabetically (by word order) ordered like this and keep the original order in another column:

- 1. "James Henry Carl Dumas" --> "Carl Dumas Henry James"
- 2. "Al Peter Karl Hito"     --> "Al Hito Karl Peter"

If on top of that I sort the rows alphabetically -->

- 1'.   "Al Peter Karl Hito"     --> "Al Hito Karl Peter"
- 2'.   "James Henry Carl Dumas" --> "Carl Dumas Henry James"

I basically have a lot of information about the content of the table which I can use to make fast searches of people: I want for example that the next input INPUT: "Henry Jam" or "Dumas Car" will give me a match.

In a programming language like "python" I will easily build some algorithm that easily discards a big chunk of the table and then another little chunk because such algorithm will know how the rows and the whole table is sorted, however I have no idea how to communicate POSTGRESQL this information so that it will use it.

I only found about an INDEX in the column "full_names" (the only relevant column) which will order the table rows in alphabetical order but I don't know how to communicate about the in-row order of words.

Is it possible to use some smart postgresql feature or to write the search algorithm in postgresql directly myself?

I'v researched about index, fulltext or writing sql code directly.

Comment: i doubt that there will be an easy solution as i couldn't differentiate the rows how to sort them and for thousands of them, it will be impossible., but when you can write it in python, you can program it in a sql procedure

Comment: You're not saving them alphabetically unless you `cluster` the table by an index that orders them that way. Even then, they aren't really stored in alphabetical order, and they will never be retrieved in that order, unless you add an `order by` when reading. If you sometimes get an ordered result without using `order by`, keep in mind it's accidental and can't be relied on.

Comment: I think your data model is not accurate. If you treat each name as a separate entity, you should normalize and have a separate table for the names.

Comment: I order them with Python and then send them to the sql table, and I save the order information in another colum like:
"james carl born" is saved as "born carl james" | {3,2,1}
But the search algorithm just needs the "fullname" column so I just reorder them after I have the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Once you save `text` values (fields, cells) that are internally sorted, they'll internally remain that way in the table.
2. When you create an index, the table won't just "get sorted" but rather the column you use as the index key will be used to build a separate structure, a binary tree. From that point, when you query the table using that column to filter, sort, etc. PostgreSQL will detect it and instead of scanning the table, it'll cllimb/descend the tree structure, which is faster. If you won't target any other columns, it'll be even faster, because it'll retrieve the value straight from the index, without having to jump from it to the table to collect anything else.

   In order to build that index, PostgreSQL analyses the entirety of those values, along with their internals - after all, it has to be able to tell `'ab'` from `'aa'`. It's already *informed* about the "in-row order of words".
3. If you plan to target individual parts of your values, split them:

   ```sql
   create table people(id serial primary key,full_name text);
   insert into people (full_name) values 
      ('James Henry Carl Dumas'),
      ('Al Peter Karl Hito');
   create table split_names as 
   select id as people_id, 
          row_number() over (partition by id order by name_part ) internal_order, 
          name_part
   from 
    ( select id, 
             regexp_split_to_table(full_name, ' ') name_part
      from people) a;

   -- people_id | internal_order | name_part
   -------------+----------------+-----------
   --         1 |              1 | Carl
   --         1 |              2 | Dumas
   --         1 |              3 | Henry
   --         1 |              4 | James
   --         2 |              1 | Al
   --         2 |              2 | Hito
   --         2 |              3 | Karl
   --         2 |              4 | Peter
   ```
4. If you plan to work with more complex text search and analysis, you might want to look at [tsvectors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-textsearch.html) and [trigrams](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.44.9).

Comment: Very thankful for the answer. I will try to learn more about point 2. I guess I need to understand B-tree. Also it makes sense that something so advanced as SQL will use "in row data" as I called it.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to use this index effectively, because something like: "WHERE "full_names" IS LIKE '%Dumas Car%' it doesn't use the index (according to Explain Analyze tool of PGadmin). And I want to use this Index before I try tsvectors of fulltext.

I guess I need to split them as in part 3. of your answer, need to look into that more.

Thanks a lot, good answer

Comment: Not using the index could mean that the index couldn't be used with a given function/operator, or PostgreSQL query planner figured it's not necessarily worth it. See this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ioUENqUh) - `~` and `like` didn't use the index, but `=` did. There are many index types and they vary in which functions/operators they support and how. Their behaviour also depends on how you maintain the table and index - search the doc for `reindex`, `cluster`, `vacuum`, `analyze`. [Also, this.](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-more-performance-for-like-and-ilike-statements/)